how do I attach new oven element which has 4 spades instead of two
Need to replace oven element. Old one has 2 spades, replacement cam with 4 - can I still use it? If so how do I attach it? Please keep it really simple.
Thank you

only you know what you have ... you have to tell us

Did you order a replacement oven element specific for your oven model or just get some type of general purpose replacement?

Did any instruction sheet come with the replacement heater?

Pictures have been known to help in these situations.  Also model numbers (including brand) of the oven and the replacement.

It is simple: You cannot use it.
Look on your oven for the make and model number.  It might be anywhere inside or outside but it will be somewhere.  Go to the manufacturer's web site or an appliance parts web site to find a parts diagram, and get the part number of the failed element.  Then do a normal internet shopping search for that part.  You can usually get them from Amazon, from appliance parts web sites in your country, or from the manufacturer or its agent in your country.
Don't install parts that don't fit.  Don't install parts that do fit.  Only install the correct part, the exact correct part, or an exact compatible model from a different vendor.
